# combine two JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am working with *Spark* in *java*. I have a *JavaPairRDD* named *Out1*

**Out1:**

```
IDCLIENT|INFO|    
1|A|    
1|C|    
1|H|    
5|R|    
2|B|
```

and I want to create a new *JavaPairRDD* named *Out2* that is the same as *Out1* without the first row:

**Out2:**

```
IDCLIENT2|INFO|    
1|C|    
1|H|    
5|R|    
2|B|
```

Afterwards, I want to combine these two *JavaPairRDD* like this:

**Out3:**

```
IDCLIENT|INFO|IDCLIENT2|
1|A,C|1|   
1|C,H|1|   
1|H,R|5|    
5|R,B|2|    
2|B| |
```

Note: We cannot use `groupByKey` because we can have the same key in more than one row.

Comment: How big is this dataset? Could you get it done in plain Scala? like: `out1.zip(out1.drop1).map{case (o1, o2)  => combine(o1,o2)}` ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no 'drop' operation in an RDD, so removing a line is a bit more difficult that one would expect.

I'd approach it using `zipWithIndex` and joining by index. It's kind of heavy but will get the job done:

```
val indexed1 = out1.zipWithIndex
val indexed2 = indexed1.map{(k,v) => ((k-1),v)}
val joined = indexed1 join indexed2
val out3 = joined.map{case (k,(v1,v2)) => format(v1,v2)}
// where format gets the values in the desired output layout
```

If the dataset would fit in memory, I'd just do a plain Scala 'oneliner':

```
out1.zip(out1.drop(1)).map{case (o1, o2) => format(o1,o2)}
```